# Automation framework for gRPC services

Tags: automated-testing, java

Are there any automation frameworks on Java for gRPC services?
For example, for functional testing of REST API could be used Rest-Assured framework. Probably, there are some framework for gRPC

Comment: can you add more details on what are you looking for ? Java and gRPC is somewhat vague

Comment: For example, for functional testing of REST API could be used Rest-Assured framework. Probably, there are some framework for gRPC.

Comment: @Artur: please edit your initial question with the information you gave us in comments here. People will see in at the first glance, which will make it easier for them to provide you with an answer.

Comment: Searching in Reddit gRPC brings up a few candidates- [getswell](http://getswell.io), [grpcannon](bojand/grpcannon), [muninrpc]( www.github.com/muninrpc/muninrpc)